# Child UITableViewController can't receive notification from Parent UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

As the question states, I am sending a notification to a child TVC and that child TVC is unable to receive the notification and excute the selector `handleNotification: (NSNotification *) paramNotif`. I.e. I **do not** get the `NSLog output` from that selector.

My code is below and is very self explanatory.

I should add that my parent TVC is also receiving a notification from a modal scene and removing itself from the center in `dealloc`, however it should still work because its the parent?

***Parent UITableViewController***

In **viewDidAppear**

```
 [self postNotificationToD5TVC];
```

In **postNotificationToD5TVC**

```
NSString *stringWithBOOL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[self.workoutRoutine boolValue]];

NSString *kNotifName2 = @"workout";

NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:kNotifName2 object:self userInfo:@{@"kworkout": stringWithBOOL}];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
```

This works fine as I have NSLogged the `method` and the value of `stringWithBool` before `Segue`

***Child UITableViewController***

I have a variable `BOOL workout`

In **viewDidLoad**

```
 [self setUpSliders:[self isRoutine]];
```

In **- (BOOL) isRoutine**

```
NSString *kNotifName2 = @"workout";

NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
               name:kNotifName2
             object:nil;

BOOL isCorrectWorkout = workout;

return isCorrectWorkout;
```

In **handleNotification:(NSNotification *) paramNotif**

```
NSString *workoutString = paramNotif.userInfo[@"kworkout"];
NSInteger workoutInt = [workoutString integerValue];
workout = workoutInt;

NSLog(@"Received notification in D5TVC and value of bool is %i",workout);
```

Comment: Why did you try to use notification for parent - child view controllers ? Whats your purpose?

Comment: @Vaisakh if changes have been made from another view controller to the parent. But this code should still work? do you know why it isnt?

Comment: i know i can just pass down information, but i want to use notifications

Answer (score 0):

Problem is I have not invoked the child TVC. So when the notification is being sent from the parent to the child, the child is not listening to the notification. So when the child TVC loads it cannot "go back" and listen to the previous notificiations.